# Ошибка при нажатии на кнопку Python Tkinter+PyScreenShot

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter

Хочу сделать программу, которая при клике на кнопку будет делать скриншот:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Screenshot!")
root.resizable(False, False)

def capture():
    ImageGrab.grab_to_file('img.png')


action = Button(root, text = "Make screenshot!", command = capture)
action.grid(columnspan = 2, row = 1, column = 0)


root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка при нажатии на кнопку:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
set_interactive(1)
```

У меня стоит **Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: pyscreenshot обязательно использовать или можно любой способ?

Comment: Я не знаю, выбрал первою попавшуюся.

Comment: Это второй питон?

Comment: Третий питон ..

Comment: связанный вопрос: [RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32754630/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не обязательно пользоваться `pyscreenshot` то можно через библиотеку `PIL` при помощи `ImageGrab`. Как прокомментировал [@jsf данный код работает только на `windows и OSX`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626508/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-python-tkinterpyscreenshot/789924?noredirect=1#comment1243862_789924)

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from PIL import ImageGrab


def capture():
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    screen.save('screenshot.png', 'PNG')


root = Tk()
root.title("Screenshot!")
root.resizable(False, False)

action = Button(root, text = "Make screenshot!", command = capture)
action.grid(columnspan=2, row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня на Ubuntu (ось упомянутая в вопросе)  **код автора как есть работает.** `pyscreenshot` в отличии от PIL.ImageGrab работает не только на Windows, OSX

Comment: @jfs к моему сожалению я не могу проверить код на `ubuntu`, только на `windows`