# Как сделать screenshot и сохранить его в переменную?

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshots

Как сделать screenshot и сохранить его в переменную, чтоб в дальнейшем с ним работать в tkinter?

---

Или по другому сформулирую

Чтобы, код работал эффективно, без сохранения в файл а потом его чтения:

```
screen = ImageGrab.grab()
screen.save('screenshot.png', 'PNG')

screen_sh = PhotoImage(file="./screenshot.png")
label = Label(can_top, image=screen_sh)
label.place(x=3, y=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну вы его просто не сохраняйте а передавайте сразу в `ImageTk.PhotoImage(screen)`

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Toplevel
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk


def capture():
    global screen, screen_sh
    top = Toplevel()
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()

    screen_sh = ImageTk.PhotoImage(screen)
    label = Label(top, image=screen_sh)
    label.pack()


root = Tk()
root.title("Screenshot!")


action = Button(root, text="Make screenshot!", command=capture)
action.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

см. [Ошибка при нажатии на кнопку Python Tkinter+PyScreenShot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626508/255866) и [Не отображается изображение в Label Python3 (Tkinter)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767818/255866)

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Comment: Как уменьшить или увеличить это изображение в 1.1% или в 1.5% ? @Twiss

Comment: @оаавирыыва как мне кажется что это тема уже для другого вопроса потому что это не особо связанно с этим. А так можете посмотреть [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251010/pil-enlarge-an-image)